# TListView OnSelectItem: why does accessing TopItem changes procedure input Item?

Tags: listview, delphi, tlistview

Reproduction: click the button to initialize the ListView, then select any item (except the first). The output in the Form caption will show that, having accessed `TopItem`, the value of `Item` has now been changed.

Can anyone explain this?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.OwnerData := True;
  ListView1.Items.Count := 5;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  Item.Caption := '...';
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1SelectItem(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
    Selected: Boolean);
var
  one, two: string;
begin
  if Item <> nil then
    one := IntToStr(Item.Index)
  else
    one := 'nil';
  if ListView1.TopItem <> nil then;
  if Item <> nil then
    two := IntToStr(Item.Index)
  else
    two := 'nil';
  Form1.Caption := one + '/' + two;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *non-virtual mode* (`OwnerData=False`), the ListView holds physical items, where every item is represented by a unique `TListItem` object in memory. But, *in virtual mode* (`OwnerData=True`), the ListView has *no physical items* at all, so no `TListItem` object is created for each item.

However, since `TListView` exposes public interfaces that use `TListItem`, and those interfaces have to continue working even in virtual mode, `TListView` holds 1 internal `TListItem` object in virtual mode, which gets **reused for any operation** that involves a `TListItem`.

So, in your example, when you select any list item, the `OnSelectItem` event is fired with a `TListItem` parameter, so `TListView` has to first fire its `OnData` event to fill the internal `TListItem` with data for the selected item.  Then, when you access the `TListView.TopItem` property, `TListView` has to fire its `OnData` event again to fill *that same internal `TListItem` object* with new data for the top visible item.

That is why you are seeing the `Item.Index` property change value.

When using virtual mode, don't expect a given `TListItem` to remain intact after you have accessed a different `TListItem`.  In fact, you should really avoid using *any* `TListItem` operations as much as possible.  If you need to access information about a particular list item, and that information is not already available in your own data source, then you should query the underlying `ListView` control using the Win32 API directly, so as not to affect the `TListView`'s sole `TListItem` object, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1SelectItem(Sender: TObject;
  Item: TListItem; Selected: Boolean);
var
  one, two: string;
begin
  if Item <> nil then
    one := IntToStr(Item.Index)
  else
    one := 'nil';

  //if ListView1.TopItem <> nil then;     // Item is affected!
  ListView_GetTopIndex(ListView1.Handle); // Item is not affected!

  if Item <> nil then
    two := IntToStr(Item.Index)
  else
    two := 'nil';

  Caption := one + '/' + two;
end;
```